# Replace Element that is apart of innerHTML with another Element

Tags: angular, angular-material, innerhtml

In an Angular application I have a base.component.

The base.component.ts file has a property `@Input() content: string;`

Within the base.component.ts file I am using a service to fetch HTML from a database.

I am assigning the HTML that is fetched from the database to the `content` property.

There are child components which extend(s) the base.component.

Inside of the child.component.html I have:

`<p [innerHTML]="content">`

in order to render the HTML that is fetched.

The HTML renders, but I would like to replace `<span class="replace-this></span>` that is apart of the fetched HTML with this `<mat-checkbox class="replacer-checkbox" formControlName="checkbox" (change)="emitData()"></mat-checkbox>`, which is hidden within the child.component.html.

Here is what the child.component.html looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <p [innerHTML]="content"></p>
  <div style="visibility: hidden;">
    <mat-checkbox class="replacer-checkbox" formControlName="checkbox" (change)="emitData()"></mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  </form>
```

I have tried using multiple methods to obtain a reference for the `<span class="replace-this></span>` element, but have had no luck.

What is the best possible way to replace what I'm trying to?

Comment: A simple string replace should do it, however "fetch HTML from a database" this is the part to fix, it is far away from being a best practice.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Just to clarify, there is a separate CMS application that allows users to modify this HTML. That is the purpose for it being stored in a database. The application I am speaking of in this question is used to fetch the HTML and display it. How do you propose I use string replace method if mat-checkbox is not of type string?

Comment: Isn't content a property in your Typescript? How is it set? Right after it's set you can run a regex against it to change content.

Comment: Yes, content is a property in my Typescript. It's set in ngOnInit. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're referring to the method String.replace() the pattern can be a regex but the replacement must be of type string, or a function that is invoked on string(s)? In my case, what I want the replacement to be is not of type string (it's the mat-checkbox)